# ZF: Why is it changing my WSDL value to HTTPS?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm passing a WSDL address with `http://`, but the call kept failing, and I've isolated the problem down to the fact that somewhere in ZF (I assume), it's altering the `http://` to `https://`, and of course I'm not running this over SSL. I can't seem to find any config options or other means to alter this, any ideas?

PHP 5.3.5, ZF 1.11.

```
$c = new Zend_Soap_Client;
$c->setWsdl('http://example.org/?wsdl');
$c->someMethod(/* params */);
```

Results in (notice the https):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in C:\ZF\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php:995
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://example...', 'urn:webservices...', 2)
#1 C:\ZF\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php(995): call_user_func(Array, '<?xml version="...', 'https://example...', 'urn:webservices...', 2)
#2 [internal function]: Zend_Soap_Client->_doRequest(Object(Zend_Soap_Client_Common), '<?xml version="...', 'https://example...', 'urn:webservices...', 2, 0)
#3 C:\ZF\library\Zend\Soap\Client\Common.php(70): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend_Soap_Client_Common), '<?xml version="...', 'https://example...', 'urn:webservices...', 2, 0)
#4 [internal function]: Zend_Soap_Client_Common->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://example...', 'urn:webservices...', 2, 0)
#5 C:\ZF\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php(1123): SoapClient->__soa in C:\ZF\library\Zend\Soap\Client.php on line 995
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in your WSDL (http://example.org/?wsdl) there are references to HTTPS. Probably the location of the server.

Comment: You are right. I have no idea why, but that is definitely the case.